# How to perform interval search using talend 5.6

Tags: talend

I have a lookup file which has a start and end range which are Long. I have my long input which can fall in this range. I have 5mil records in my lookup.

I have tried tIntervalMatch and this seems to be very slow.

Is there any alternative ?

Comment: add more details on what is the expected outcome, what is sample data input and in lookup file , what is the performance you are getting..very slow  needs to be explained with what is the row/sec processing you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Below are the sample lookup file  16777216,16777471,"AU","","","",-27.0000,133.0000,0
16777472,16778239,"CN","","","",35.0000,105.0000,0
16778240,16778367,"AU","07","Prahran","3181",-37.8500,145.0000,0
16778368,16778495,"AU","07","Malvern East","3145",-37.8775,145.0624,0
16778496,16778751,"AU","07","Melbourne","3000",-37.8232,144.9729,0 and my input is 16777218 then I need the first look up to be selected. currently I am getting 10 rec/sec as the file is 300 MB and has around 5 mil records. I need to achieve more than 1000 recs/sec.

Comment: I will again explain what I am trying to achieve. We are getting registration events and which has ip address in it. We want to perform a range based look up which can be stored in a db or file. We tried storing it in a mysql table and that seems to be very slow about 1 to 5 recs/sec . So I was trying with tIntervalMatch and that seem be slow as well(rows/sec mentioned above) I dont know if we can use a tMap to achieve this with >= and <= join condition.